# Angular CLI shared folder sub-folders

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular-cli, zonejs

One of the 'shared' folders in a the angular 2 is getting quite full with services/models so I would like to move files into sub-folders of the shared folder

I'd like to go from this folder structure:

```
app
 - shared
   - test.service.ts
```

to

```
app
 - shared
   -sub-folder
     -test.service.ts
```

When I do so the app transpiles and the CLI creates a build but in the browser there is an error:

```
http://localhost:4200/app/shared/test.service.js 404 (Not Found).......zone.js:101

                                 ^- notice the location is not resolved correctly
```

Above file location is missing **/sub-folder/**

I've got all the imports done correctly (I've moved the test.service.ts file in and out of the sub folder and once its out of the sub-folder and back into shared folder it works fine...everything loads/no errors)

I've also updated the 'system-config.ts' file to include the 'app/shared/sub-folder' barrel, and added the index.ts with appropriate exports in the 'sub-folder'

How can I (or can I) use sub folders in the shared folder?

Comment: Can you share a plunker with the entire app? I think you probably need to change your `import` statement in your app, but I can't be sure without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `src/app/shared/sub-folder/test.service.ts`

`import {TestService} from './shared/sub-folder/test.service';`

This works without changing any configuration files in `system-config.js`.

Depending what folders you change and what configurations you change.
You need to restart you server, and sometimes you need to run `ng buld`.

If the problem still is there, try reinstalling `angular-cli`.